# Ansible Role: MySQL unable to read configuration file

Tags: mysql, yaml

I've received the following error.

```
'msg': 'AnsibleError: unable to read /the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2', 'failed': True
```

I tried the following playbook configure.yml.

```
# file: roles/mysql/tasks/configure.yml
---
- hosts: test
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: MySQL | Update the my.cnf
     action: template src=/the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2 dest=/etc/mysql/my.cnf owner=root group=root mode=0644
     notify:
       - restart mysql
`
while executimg this by this command: ansible-playbook configure.yml
the following error appears.
>>>>>
fatal: [test] => {'msg': 'AnsibleError: unable to read /the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2', 'failed': True}
fatal: [test] => {'msg': 'AnsibleError: unable to read /the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2', 'failed': True}
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Does `/the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2` exist?

Comment: Check the permissions and ownership to make sure that the webserver can access it, this is as simple as comparing the permissions of that file against the file which does load.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file /the-ansibles/roles/mysql/templates/etc_mysql_my.cnf.j2 exist on the machine that ansible is running from?

Templated files need to be on the local machine not the remote.